# How to get text "BTC" from tickerid "Binance:BTCUSDT" [Pine Script Trading View]

Tags: split, pine-script

I want to get text "BTC" from tickerid "BINANCE:BTCUSDT". How to split them? Please help me.

TradingView - PineScript

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution or a solution just for this string?

Comment: I'd be interested in a generic solution. syminfo.ticker gives you BTCUSDT, but for other tickers, eg. DOGEUSDT, there can be more than 3 characters. It would be great to just be able to get the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will split the `tickerid` using `:` as a delimeter. It will then return the first three characters of the pair.

Read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/script/l0wdrsUO-String-Manipulation-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/) for more string manupilation related functions.

```
//@version=5
indicator("String Test", overlay=true)

getPair(_str, _n) =>
    string[] _pair = str.split(_str, ":")
    string[] _chars = str.split(array.get(_pair, 1), "")
    int _len = array.size(_chars)
    int _end = math.min(_len, math.max(0, _n))
    string[] _substr = array.new_string(0)
    if _end <= _len
        _substr := array.slice(_chars, 0, _end)
    string _return = array.join(_substr, "")

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, 0, getPair(syminfo.tickerid, 3), yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

[image]